# Can the prepositional phrase "at ease" be used with "very"?

Tags: grammaticality, usage, prepositional-phrases

https://ludwig.guru/s/very+at+ease

According to this, "at ease" is used with "very", is it grammatical? I've learnt that "very" can be used only with adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: *Very at ease* is good in casual speech, but not so much in writing. *Very* is used with adverbs very commonly, very easily, and very well.

Comment: "very" can be used only with adjectives? *I've [**very rarely**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+rarely%2Cvery+often&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) seen such a daft assertion!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I forgot adverbs. Sorry.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Can I also say "someone put me very at ease"?

Comment: Well, my guess is "at ease" is an adverbial element, so I don't really understand what this question is getting at

Comment: @FumbleFingers Technically, it's a prepositional phrase. You can't say I'm very in a bad mood.

Comment: I am OK with _very at ease_, but I might be slightly happier with _very much at ease_, and, indeed, _very much in a bad mood_.

Comment: I don't see the relevance - maybe you can't say *I'm very in a bad mood*, but you can certainly say [*I feel **very at ease***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+very+at+ease&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I'm not really interested in such terminology, but if it led you to categorize ***at ease*** and ***in a bad mood*** as having the same syntactic constraints, it's obviously not doing you much good either! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's my fault. Do you want me to delete this post?

Comment: Not at all! But I don't know how this "parts of speech" terminology would enable you to differentiate between ***at ease*** and ***in a bad mood***. There obviously ***is*** a difference in syntactic affordances, though. Presumably there's a reason why you can be ***very in touch*** with something, but not ***very in a good mood***.

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm **uneasy** about all these answers in comments.

Comment: If you look at the publications on ludwig/guru, the answer is yes unless they are quoting something odd, which they usually do not.

Answer (score -1):

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/at-ease) says synonyms of "at ease" are "relaxed, secure, comfortable, informal". Those are adjectives.

While "at ease" may be a "prepositional phrase" it often assumes the roll of an adjective in a sentence.

"Very" is an intensifier that's able to modify an adjective.

Can the prepositional phrase "at ease" be used with "very"? Yes.

However, it sounds casual, and isn't a formal written style.

Comment: Feedback is welcome, I am not adverse to changing the answer.